# Answering by uploading a Jupyter notebook/Download as notebook

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, export

A quick story: Today I found myself trying out some Python code from Stack Overflow straight into [Colab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Colaboratory) (Google Jupyter), making a new code cell for every code block.

At some point I thought, why not copying also the text, into text boxes, so I won't need to switch while I try it out?

After putting them side by side I thought that notebook would be a perfect import/export/answer format for single Stack Overflow answers, giving also that Jupyter supports [vast number of languages and kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels).

Down here you can find a quick comparison of the post I was looking at and the final result on Jupyter (Colab).

Not quite a feature request, but more of an idea.

### Original Stack Overflow answer

[image]

### Jupyter Notebook version

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the feature-request is here. Are you asking that Stack Overflow allow answers that are just links to Jupyter Notebooks? I don't see that happening; we don't allow answers that are just links to any of the various *Fiddle sites.

Comment: I see the notebook more as a format to import/export in case, for example, I would like to try out an answer. I'm not thinking of partnership or linking external resources.